# How can I open a webpage first and then fill in text boxes and click a button and visibly view the results?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

[edit] **It is a requirement that the webpage spawn and open in IE and allow user manual interaction after the programmatic actions have completed.**[/edit]

I've seen a lot of code examples online about opening webpages or filling in webpage textboxes and getting a return value without ever opening them visibly.

> I would like to open a webpage in IE, fill in a few textbox buttons
>   and then click the submit button and view the results visibly.

I am able to do this with a **dll** called **Selenium**, but I do not want to use a 3rd party application and it seems that `WebBrowser()` should be able to do this?

I can post my failed code examples if that would help.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your app is web form or win form

Comment: A win form that as one of its functions should start IE, open a page, prefill in a few boxes and click a button.

Comment: A good example of what I would like to do is this project (which I have gotten working)
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5452/Microsoft-Web-Browser-Automation-using-C
But without the extra needed DLL's and I'd like the browser to be IE instead of the plugin object generic browser.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this qould fit better as a comment, but I don't have enoigh reputation.

Do you know how HTTP-Forms work?
It would probably be easier to send a HTTP-Request to the target of the form you want to fill, including the parameters you would like to fill into the form.

So you don't need any WebBrowser or similar, just a simple HttpWebRequest object, where you specity the target, the method (very likely POST) and the data you'd like to send.

Comment: If I'm understanding you properly, this will not work as I need to see the page load, programmatically interact with the page and have it continue to a point where then human interaction is required in said loaded page.

Comment: @Jay you're right, I didn't know there was other interaction with the webpage, except the stuff done by your program

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **webbrowser** control in Winforms. It is possible to access every DOM object of the website using the control. **No need to open the IE** externally.

You just need to specify the webbrowser URL as your link.
Then, fill the textboxes with code,

```
BrowserID.Document.GetElementById("TextboxID").SetAttribute("Value", "NewVaue")
```

Also, you can click on the button using `InvokeMember("click")`.

There are lots of stuff using **WebBrowser**. You can learn it [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?384076-Webbrowser-Control-Tip-and-Examples).

Comment: I'm going to edit my original question if I can to make this more obvious, it is a requirement that the webpage spawn and open in IE.